# drupal_render() is deprecated. What replaces it?

Tags: wysiwyg, 8

I have a render array and I want to convert it to HTML and place it in a WYSIWYG field. What is the generally accepted way to do that since drupal_render() is deprecated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was [replaced with the renderer service](https://www.drupal.org/node/2939099).

```
$render_service = \Drupal::service('renderer');
```

As mpdonadio and 4k4 have pointed out in the comments, to prevent metadata from bubbling up to the main request, you should execute this in a new render context. You can do so by using the `renderPlain` method, rather than the usual `render` method (unless you're returning this from a controller, in which case use `renderRoot` instead).

```
$rendered = $render_service->renderPlain($build);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be done in a new render context to prevent any metadata from bubbling to the main one for the page?

Comment: @mpdonadio I'm sure you're right, but I haven't found it necessary the one or two times I've used this. Probably a result of where/when I'm calling it

Comment: Yes, in this case you should use a new render context, with `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderPlain($renderArray)` or `->renderRoot()` if this delivers the result from a controller.

Comment: @4k4 Thanks for the info, that's very useful to know. I incorporated it into the answer

Comment: @rjacobsen0 You're very welcome, but please see the edit as it has some potentially important information :)

Comment: Got your edit. Thanks! Here's my edited example for anyone who needs it. 
`$newBodyValueHtml = drupal_render($newBodyValueRenderArray);` becomes `$render_service = \Drupal::service('renderer');
  $newBodyValueHtml = $render_service->renderPlain($newBodyValueRenderArray);`

Answer (score 1):

[This documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/the-drupal-8-render-pipeline) is the best place to have the most accurate/up-to-date documentation about the rendering pipeline and its methods - such as `drupal_render()` - in Drupal 8+.